# How to link a webview to a service class in Xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have created a webview in `Mainpage.xaml`:

```
<WebView x:Name="browserlink"
         VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
```

Inside `MainPage.xaml.cs` :

```
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DependencyService.Resolve<IWebView>().StartMyWebView();
    }

    void Exit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }

}
```

In a service class I created the following class:

```
    [Service(Enabled = true, Exported = false)]
    public class WebViewService : Service, IWebView
    {
        public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
        {
            CreateWebView();
            return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
        }

        public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
        {
            return null;
        }

        void CreateWebView()
        {
           // call WebView with the name browserlink from Mainpage.xaml
        }

        string channelID = "ForeGroundServiceChannel";
        var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
        if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.O)
        {
            var notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(channelID, channelID, NotificationImportance.Low);
            notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }

        var notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelID)
                                      .SetContentTitle("BackGroundServiceStarted")
                                      .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Mipmap.icon)
                                      .SetContentText("Service is running in backgound")
                                      .SetPriority(1)
                                      .SetOngoing(true)
                                      .SetChannelId(channelID)
                                      .SetAutoCancel(true);
        StartForeground(1001, notificationBuilder.Build());

    }

    public void StartMyWebView()
    {
        var intent = new Intent(Android.App.Application.Context, typeof(WebViewService));
        Android.App.Application.Context.StartForegroundService(intent);
    }
}
}
```

How do I make the webview in the `Mainpage.xaml` run the website I created inside the service class?

Comment: I don't think this is doing what you think it is.  Your service class is just instantiating its own copy of a WebView, not starting a web server

Comment: You are right, Let's assume that I don't have any code inside the CreateWebView() method. What would you do in this case ?

Comment: just generally, if you want to connect to a self hosted web service, you would use localhost and the port number

Comment: That is entirely different thing. I need to invoke the Webview first.

Comment: Why are you embedding a UI element in a service class?

Comment: My idea is to run the WebView in the background. Let's say a website that has a playback so, I want that playback to keep running even though the app is sent to the background.

Comment: there are numerous existing questions and posts about background processing.  This is NOT the way to do it

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you share some links to the this matter.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=backgrounded+xamarin+site%253Astackoverflow.com

Comment: It is better to operate the WebView in the `MainPage.xaml.cs` or the `Viewmodel`.